# Symfony2.0.10 register function YEAR from DoctrineExtensions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am forced to work with old symfony2.0.10 and want to register YEAR form https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions so I add to deps and reinstall

```
[DoctrineExtensions]
git=https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions
```

and register in my config.yml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   %database_driver%
    host:     %database_host%
    port:     %database_port%
    dbname:   %database_name%
    user:     %database_user%
    password: %database_password%
    charset:  UTF8

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    auto_mapping: true
    dql:
        datetime_functions:
            DAY: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Day
            MONTH: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
            YEAR: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year
```

but I have got this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ExceptionHandler::handle() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ExceptionHandler.php:57 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ExceptionHandler->handle(Object(Error)) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ExceptionHandler.php on line 57

edit: and this is my code doing eror

```
class NewsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    $emConfig = $this->_em->getConfiguration();
        $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('YEAR', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Year');
        $emConfig->addCustomDatetimeFunction('MONTH', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month');


    $q = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()->select('YEAR(news.datetime) as ye, MONTH(news.datetime) as me' )
        ->from('LittonMainBundle:News', 'news')
        ->orderBy('news.datetime', 'DESC');
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Where is running this code?

Comment: In repository to my entity in controller

Comment: 1.) You can't really use sf2.0 with php 7 2.) That's not a valid php class.

Comment: so it is no way to pin DoctrineExensions or something like it to haveyear function?

Comment: `NewsRepository` isn't valid php, you should fix that first